# How to perform multiple actions in one line of code in R

Tags: r, string

I'm quite new to R and am trying to find better ways to structure my code.
Is it possible to perform more than one action in one line of code?

i.e I'm trying to remove certain characters from strings in my list:

```
pattern1 = "_score.txt"
pattern2 = "filler"
pattern3 = "_names"
sample_names <- str_remove(sample_names, pattern1) 
sample_names <- str_remove(sample_names, pattern2) 
sample_names <- str_remove(sample_names, pattern3)
```

Is there any way I could combine the three "sample_names <- str_remove" steps into one?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not confident enough in using regex to identify all the patterns you want to remove or if you want to do it in a more stepwise fashion for other readers then you can also do:

```
library(stringr)
samples_names %>% str_remove(pattern1) %>% str_remove(pattern2) %>% str_remove(pattern3)
```

But I should mention using `str_remove_all()` is the shortest and cleanest method as answered above if the primary objective is to cut the lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `str_remove_all` with `pattern` vector joined to create a single one with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(sample_names, str_c(c(pattern1, pattern2, pattern3), collapse="|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_remove_all` instead of `str_remove`, because you want to remove multiple or repeated patterns at once.

Then you put a pipe character `|` between each pattern to symbolize `OR`.

Test data and slightly different code:

```
sample_names <- c("This is test 1_score.txt",
                  "this is filler test 2",
                  "this is _names test 3",
                  "test4_filler_names_score.txt",
                  "test5_filler_filler_filler")

library(stringr)
str_remove_all(sample_names, "_score.txt|filler|_names")
```